# How no fix JobScheduler (not Scheduling tasks)

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduler, schedule

Trying to work with JobScheduler like this:
get JobScheduler:

```
private val scheduler: ScheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
```

And trying to send broadcast at specific time:

```
scheduler.schedule(
                    {
                        sendBroadcast(intent)
                    },
                    timeToWait,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                )
```

But broadcast not sending. scheduler not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of "doze mode".